# Adding users to Unix groups only if said groups exist (puppet)

Tags: linux, unix, puppet

I tried using [the 'group' attribute of the 'user' resource](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/user.html) like so :

```
user {
"user":
    group  => ["docker", "www-data"]
}
```

If the groups 'docker' and 'www-data' exist on the client, the user will be added to the groups without issue. However, if one of the groups doesn't exist, puppet client will error out and won't add the user to any of the groups in the array.

How do I make sure puppet ignores a group if it doesn't exist and add the user to the other ones that do anyway?

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally not how Puppet (and most configuration management frameworks) are designed to be used.

A good way of remembering it is that the intention of a declarative language is to *declare* the state you wish the system to be in. The declaration should be the "single source of truth" and is equivalent of saying "I want all cars that are built by this assembly line to be red, have four doors and four wheels".

With that in mind, Puppet will not know that the groups do not exist, and will attempt to enforce your declared state, regardless.

The fix to this is to create the groups, and enforce explicit dependencies so that they are created before the user is created. To be clear, Puppet does draw *implicit* dependencies between resources, but I've always found it more helpful to be *explicit* when referring to other resources for the sake of increasing readability and reducing ambiguity.

```
group { ['docker', 'www-data']:
  ensure => present,
}

user { 'user':
  group   => ['docker', 'www-data'],
  require => Group['docker', 'www-data'],
}
```

Notes:

- Single quotes should always be used unless the string contains a variable
- The name of the resource should be on the same line as the resource type
- When referring to other resources for dependencies, the first character of the resource type is capitalised

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, puppet only directly cares about what *you* care about. Craig gives a nice explanation in that answer.

With that said, it's likely (and recommended) puppet is managing the stacks which provide a docker service (with a docker group) and a web server (with a www-data group).

For example, somewhere in the code where you install docker and apache, explicitly declare the groups you need:

```
group { 'docker':
  ensure => present,
  system => true,
}
group { 'www-data':
  ensure => present,
  system => true,
}
```

Now you can use collectors to modify resources, irrespective of the above code actually being deployed to every server. This will *conditionally* add users to groups if Puppet is managing those specific groups on the server being deployed.

```
Group <| title == 'docker' |> {
  members +> 'user'
}
```

The above means, *search for any `group` resource with the `title` **docker**, if it's found add **user** to the `members` attribute*.

https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/lang_resources.html#lang_resource_syntax-adding-or-modifying-attributes